# What is the best way to organize webapi controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have some classes such as `Customer`, `Book`, `Movie`, `Game`.
I created 4 Controllers per each entity to do CRUD and specify logic per each.
Now the question is I would like to retrieve a list games by `customerId`
Should I put the method action in `CustomerController` or `GamesController`?
The route will be like this `"/api/customers/123/games"`
And the same with Book, Movie. So 3 methods in each controller Book, Game, Movie or 3 methods in Customer controller 
So what is the best way to manage this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the point to understand is that web api is largely REST based. And rest is Resource based, so if you are returning the resource Games, then your GamesController should handle it. Simple

It would be funny to have your Customer controller return games.
By default your Games controller will have something like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/games/{customerId}"]
public List<Games> Get(int customerId)
{
    // get games from repository
    return games;
}
```

take an example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TripsController: ApiController
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IQueryDispatcher _queryDispatcher;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TripsController"/> class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryDispatcher">Query Dispatcher</param>
    public TripsController(IQueryDispatcher queryDispatcher)
    {
        if (queryDispatcher == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryDispatcher));
        _queryDispatcher = queryDispatcher;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Actions

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("trips", Name = "TripList")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]TripsQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (query == null)
                return BadRequest();
            var result = _queryDispatcher.Dispatch<TripsQuery, TripsQueryResult>(query);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.AddPaginationHeader(query, result, new UrlHelper(Request), "TripList");

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("trips/{tripId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]TripDetailsQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _queryDispatcher.Dispatch<TripDetailsQuery, TripDetailsQueryResult>(query);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class StopsController: ApiController
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IQueryDispatcher _queryDispatcher;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="StopsController"/> class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryDispatcher">Query Dispatcher</param>
    public StopsController(IQueryDispatcher queryDispatcher)
    {
        if (queryDispatcher == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryDispatcher));
        _queryDispatcher = queryDispatcher;
    }

    #endregion

    [Route("trips/{tripId}/stops", Name = "StopList")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]StopsQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (query == null)
                return BadRequest();
            var result = _queryDispatcher.Dispatch<StopsQuery, StopsQueryResult>(query);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.AddPaginationHeader(query, result, new UrlHelper(Request), "StopList");
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    [Route("trips/{tripId}/stops/{stopId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]StopDetailsQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (query == null)
                return BadRequest();
            var result = _queryDispatcher.Dispatch<StopDetailsQuery, StopDetailsQueryResult>(query);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```

So you see, a Trip can have more than one stops, but the way you retreive stops is still in the stops controller but just have the routes mapped properly

Comment: Hi Jinish, If you put it in GameController, Your route will be api/games/123 => This route gets single game by id not getting a list game by customer. I think the route should be the same  in CustomerController "api/customers/123/games". Just either we put it in CustomerController or GameController.

Comment: That's correct. But the only difference is that if we talk in terms of REST and what it represents, then games should be returned by the GamesController. You could ofcourse use attribute routing and have that endpoint that returns games anywhere else as well. But since you asked about the best way (possibly best practice), so I suggested the above

Comment: No, I mean put it in GameController is correct as you explained but change from [Route("api/games/{customerId}"] to [Route("api/customers/{customerId}/games"]

Comment: aah..right, sorry my bad. the route should be something like : [Route("customers/{customerId}/games")]. But it should still go in the Games controller.

Comment: Yes, I agree it should be in GameController. About the route how do you think between "api/customers/{customerid}/games" and "api/games/customers/{customerid}"

Comment: I just added an example from one of my personal apps. To answer your question, I would go with the first one, i.e. api/customers/{customerid}/games simply because it tells me that customers have games. The second was is confusing to understand the relation

Comment: Nice. that is perfect route setting. Just want to discuss with you more on other stuff. I think you should make generic exception handler to handle try catch, you dont have to specify them in every action. Also the generic way to return Badrequest if param is null that will reduce a huge lines of code

Comment: Yes. This is from an old branch actually. The final product implements some cross cutting in design especially exception handling. I was following a good article on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling. A good read!